# How to append a string in a specific place in a list

Tags: r

If I have a list

```
Mylist <- list("This", "list", "is", "mine")
```

Now I want to add a string "3rd" to the third position so when I print(Mylist)

```
This

list

3rd

is

mine
```

I will want to be able to do this multiple times for any number in the list I choose.

Thank you in advance, I cannot find any resource that tells me how to do this.

Comment: `append(Mylist, "3rd", 2)`...? Re "to do this multiple times" -- that's maybe a bad idea. My understanding is that R vectors (including lists) don't behave very efficiently under repeated ad hoc insertions like this... they are not linked lists, just vectors.

Comment: Yeah I do, I have an output from a different file that needs appending in 4000+ places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if this will give you exactly what you want but if you know the positions where you should insert the new values that you might be able to do something like the following

```
x <- 1:10              # Vector with original values
y <- c("A", "B", "C")  # Vector to be inserted

idx <- seq_len(length(x))  # Dummy index
idx2 <- c(3, 6, 7)+.1  # Index of insertions (put a wee bit)

c(x, y)[order(c(idx, idx2))]

[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "A"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "B"  "7"  "C"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

This can also be transferred to lists.